# How to get project language from sonarqube API?

Tags: sonarqube

How can I get the main programming language of a project, using sonarqube API? Or a list of all of the project's programming languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per SonarQube [Metric Definitions documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions) :

> *ncloc_language_distribution* - Non Commenting Lines of Code Distributed By Language.

Use that with SonarQube WebAPI *api/measures* (documentation [embedded](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API) in your SonarQube server) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!
My usage: api/measures/component?componentKey=[key]&metricKeys=ncloc_language_distribution

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve the same problem, I came up with a small shell script that writes a list of all SonarQube project keys and the language distribution for the given project:

```
#!/bin/bash

API="http://my.sonar-server.com:9000/sonar/api"  ### adjust this!
API_LANG_DIST="$API/measures/component?metricKeys=ncloc_language_distribution"

# get a list of all project keys:
projKeys=$(curl -s "$API/projects/index" | jq -r '.[].k')

# for each project key, get the language distribution metric:
for key in ${projKeys}; do
    langDist=$(curl -s "${API_LANG_DIST}&componentKey=${key}" | jq '.component.measures[0].value')
    printf "%-80s%-80s\n" ${key} ${langDist}
done
```

The output will be something like this:

```
com.mycompany:projectA      "grvy=75;java=4091"
com.mycompany:projectB      "css=1966;java=52770;js=11460;less=1862"
com.mycompany:projectC      "css=40185;java=11451;js=13757"
```

*Note:* This script makes use of the `jq` JSON parsing utility. If you do not have it available, you can install it for example via `sudo yum install jq`.

(Tested on SonarQube 5.6.6 and 6.7.0)